# Easy way to make vector triplet in CPP

Tags: c++, vector

What would be an easy way to construct a vector triplet of ints in CPP?

i.e instead of a pair of 2 ints ,

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > vec;
```

I want 3 int's tied together as one element of the vector.

I realized one way would be to make 2 sub-nested pairs, but this method gets messy. I am not aware of all the details of CPP, therefore please recommend an easier way if available. Thank you.

Comment: use [std::tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982837.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the super fast reply, I am trying tuples :)

Comment: i've done 
    typedef tuple <int, int, int> triplet;

but am getting the error: tuple does not name a type

Comment: I think I have to update my compiler for using tuples, going for struct instead :)

Comment: @rohanag: You need to `#include <tuple>` and use `std::`: `std::tuple<int, int, int>`.

Comment: What does the triplet represent?

Comment: @Peter Wood , the triplet reperesents 3 integers

Comment: @GManNickG , I did both of those things :) The error was as follows:

c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

Comment: @rohanag ... and what do the integers represent? I'm suggesting encapsulating the data (c:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need to over-engineer.

```
struct Triplet
{
  int  one_, two_, three_;
};

vector<Triplet> triplets;
```

Answer (score 15):

`std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int>> myvec;`

Answer (score 3):

Check out boost tuple http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html

You can easily create Pairs, triples, quadruples, up to n-uples!

Answer (score -1):

In C++11, there is `std::array`, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). In C++03, I would probably define a struct of 3 `int`s and make a vector of those.